# Cloudinary Change Public ID

Tags: cloudinary

I have been using Cloudinary to store images, and I want to change the public ID scheme I've been using. Is there any way to update the current public IDs to new ones using the admin API?

For example, if I have an image with a public ID of 1, can I change it to 2 without re-uploading the photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `rename` API. 
For more information (in Rails):
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload#rename_images